# Python: Mutated List values upon index() call?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, indexing

I have a dictionary of lists, a list of lists, and a dictionary framework.  Every key in `p` does not contain the same number of lists, nor in the same order.  I want to standardize the dictionary in `q`.  In order to initially populate `q`:

```
p = {'GET25' : [['20151231', 57000], ['20150930', 135000]],
     'ABC10' : [['20151231', 10000], ['20150930', 195000]]}
ol2 = [['20160331', 0], ['20151231', 0], ['20150930', 0]]
q = {}

for key in p:
    q[key] = ol2
```

Leaves this framework:

```
q = {'GET25' : [['20160331', 0], ['20151231', 0], ['20150930', 0]],
     'ABC10' : [['20160331', 0], ['20151231', 0], ['20150930', 0]]}
```

At this point, `ol2` is still intact.  Now I want to populate the appropriate list in `q` with the values in `p`.  This is my code:

```
for key in p:
    for each in p[key]:
        q[key][ol2.index([each[0], 0])][1] = each[1]
```

What I thought this code was supposed to do was: return the index of the "quarter-end date" in the list `ol2`, then set the value in `q` to the value in `p` in the corresponding location.  However, eventually a `Value Error` is returned: `['20151231', 0] is not in list`.  And when I `print(ol2)`, I find that my list has been mutated:

```
>>>print(ol2)
[['20160331', 0], ['20151231', 10000], ['20150930', 195000]]
```

I don't really know where I'm resetting the values in `ol2` or how to prevent.  Thanks for the help.

EDIT:
In response to a question on this post, my desired output would be:

```
q = {'GET25' : [['20160331', 0], ['20151231', 57000], ['20150930', 135000]],
     'ABC10' : [['20160331', 0], ['20151231', 10000], ['20150930', 195000]]}
```

Comment: Could you also explain in your question what your desired output would be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `q[key] = ol2` in the loop, you set all keys to the same value, namely `ol2`.  Not copies of `ol2`.  They are all the same list.  So when you modify `q[key]` later, you modify all the values (as well as `ol2`).

If you want to set each value to a separate copy of `ol2`, you'll have to `import copy` use `q[key] = copy.deepcopy(ol2)`, because your list is nested so you (presumably) need to deep-copy all the lists.